# get active tab by click in django form template

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

I am developing my first Django app and want to optimize it. How can I get the last active tab in my form template? I want to be redirected from the create or update form to the last active tab on the page. I haven't any knowledge in JavaScript, so I am hoping for some help.

I just add to my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        });

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
            var id = $(e.target).attr("href");
            localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', id)
        });

        var selectedTab = localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');
        if (selectedTab != null) {
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + selectedTab + '"]').tab('show');
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to post information about the user interface (active tab), you are going to need to put that into your form somehow. My preference would be to do that via JavaScript (I'll show it in [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) here just because it may be easier to understand) by attaching an event to the tab (or modifying the existing event) to update a hidden field in your form, e.g.,

```
$(function () {
// assumes an id=myhiddenfield on html element
var form_field = $('#myhiddenfield');
// assumes your tabs all have a class of 'tabs', adds click element
$('.tabs').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // assign current tab's html id to form field
  form_field.val(this.id);
});
})
```

With that you should have the value of the tab in your form, but you will need to add a new field to your Django form's definition with a widget type of `forms.HiddenInput()` to hold the value and then update `myhiddenfield` above with the name of that input's CSS id.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To this point I understand what I am supposed to do. But how do I implement this? I tried to create a JavaScript File and load it to my template but it doesn't worked.

Comment: What part doesn't work? Your file doesn't load or the code throws an error? You will need to include jQuery as well, which you can [get from their CDN](https://code.jquery.com/). If your file isn't loading, it's probably means you have a problem with your [static file setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/). The easiest thing in that case would be to put this code inside a `<script>` block on the page for now. But it should also be updated to run on page load. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you could easily do so by assign the tag a active class.

```
<div class='active'></div>
```

Comment: This would be a static class. What I want to do is to get a dynamic function which adds the active class to the tab which is clicked on.

Comment: In that case, you could use jQuery to assign this class attribute to the tag, like: `$("#tag_id").attr('class', 'active')`